# Is there a daily usage endpoint for Google Plus API?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Is there an endpoint for the google api to find out how many requests I have left in my 10k daily limit? I know I can sign into my account and view it, but I would like to integrate the number directly into my application.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to grab the quota within the API. It honestly may be easier to just rate limit or backoff when you see the quota errors- https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits for example.

If you were using the [Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api-rate-limits) or [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas) you can check the project quota overall.